Updating multiple EntraID user displaynames via Microsoft Graph with a Suffix
I am a MgGraph beginner and would like to update multiple EntraID user objects with a suffix to their displayname.
Specifically it's about external users which I have invited to our organization's EntraID and would search for them based on their external email domain. Then, I like to add the suffix " | External" to their displayname in our directory.
So it would have to be a "addition task" where the MgGraph action performs a filtered search, followed by adding the suffix to the displayname.
Could anyone help me with the correct syntax in that?
I was following already this guide for updating the static companyname of the newly invited external users. But now struggling with performing the "addition" to an existing value (displayname).
